# Connecting a 'clicked' signal to the indicator

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I wrote a PanelMenu.Button-derived class for shell 3.36 by following the tutorial at:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing

Everything works (after a few 3.36-related tweaks I had to do) but now I would like to have a single left click show/hide the application and single right click open the menu. For that I wanted to catch a 'clicked' signal but PanelMenu.Button only emits `menu-set`. I'd need something like this:

`indicator.connect("clicked", () => GLib.spawn_command_line_async("my_app"));`

Is there a widget that supports the 'clicked' signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think looking for a another widget might be more work than it's worth. If you look [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/gnome-3-36/js/ui/panelMenu.js#L133-L140) at the implementation, they're really just overriding the `event` vfunc to open the menu.

```js
vfunc_event(event) {
    if (this.menu &&
        (event.type() == Clutter.EventType.TOUCH_BEGIN ||
         event.type() == Clutter.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS))
        this.menu.toggle();

    return Clutter.EVENT_PROPAGATE;
}
```

If you've subclassed yourself and don't need the menu, you can simply do a similar thing just by redefining the virtual function like so (just put this in your subclass like a regular function):

```js
vfunc_event() {
    if ((event.type() == Clutter.EventType.TOUCH_BEGIN ||
         event.type() == Clutter.EventType.BUTTON_PRESS))
        GLib.spawn_command_line_async("my_app");

    return Clutter.EVENT_PROPAGATE;
}
```

However, you may want to change the events to `BUTTON_RELEASE` and `TOUCH_END` so it happens when the user *releases* the button, giving them a chance to change their mind by dragging the mouse away.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! A small follow-up question: is there a preferred way to show/hide a window of a running application? Spawning it works but it feels like an overkill if the application is already running. In other words, how do I connect the extension to a running instance of a specific application?

Comment: You probably want to look at https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/shell01~0.1_api-appsystem/ or open a new question if you need more detailed help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:
`indicator.connect("button-press-event", () => GLib.spawn_command_line_async("my_app"));`

The **signal** you are looking for should be: *button-press-event*.
A single left mouse button click will trigger the *button-press-event*. 

This signal works for me. My GNOME shell version is: 3.36.9

Regarding your second question:
*is there a preferred way to show/hide a window of a running application?*

 This link may be able to help you or will hopefully at least give you some pointers in the right direction:
https://github.com/amivaleo/Show-Desktop-Button/blob/master/extension.js

Good Luck!